# Selecionar registro que possui um campo date usando apenas o ano no where

Tags: mysql

Como posso fazer um SELECT no banco de dados no qual os registros possuem um campo que o formato é DATE Ex:(2017-05-15) e na clausula WHERE eu quero por apenas o ano. Tambem queria saber se é melhor usar as datas no banco de dados em formato varchar ou no formato date mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função *Year*:

```
SELECT * from tabela WHERE YEAR(campo_data) = '2017'
```

Ou *Extract*:

```
SELECT * from tabela WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM campo_data) = '2017'
```

Se é melhor usar *Date* ou *Varchar* vai depender da necessidade, o tipo de dado infere nos recursos que estarão disponíveis. A vantagem de usar o *Date* é que funções específicas de data podem ser úteis, como a usada acima.

Comment: Por que dependeria da necessidade se ao meu ver pelo o que você falou o Date fornece muito mais vantagens? O formato Date possui alguma desvantagem em comparação ao Varchar? Ou isso é questão de gosto do programador?

Comment: Vai além do gosto do programador, envolve semântica, desempenho e recursos disponiveis. Funciona armazenar um valor numérico em um campo texto, já formatado, mas não é semântico e em operações matemáticas vai exigir conversões. O mesmo se enquadra para a data. Tratando-se de banco de dados, é importante pensar no tipo de dado devido indexação e tempo de processamento, comparações, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode declarar em uma variável o ano atual, exemplo:

```
$data = date('Y');
```

Depois e só jogar no *where*!